# Quick ValueTuple initialization with 1 argument

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, unboxing, valuetuple

I want to create a simple way to create a matrix-like structure for users. This means that the user can define rows and columns.
For now its looks like this:

```
var matrix = new()
{
   new() { Item1, Item2 } // Row
   new() { Item3, Item4 } // Row
}
```

Pretty good, but for large matrices it already looks not compact enough.
I try to use ValueTuple for creating matrices:

```
(
 (Item1, Item2),
 (Item3, Item4)
)
```

And it works, but if we try to create matrix with 2 row and 1 column it will be reversed.

```
(
 (Item1),
 (Item2)
)
```

Previous code the same as:

```
(
 Item1, Item2
)
```

Is exist any way to disable automatic unboxing ValueTuple's in C#?
So that `(Item1)` will be equals `ValueTuple.Create(Item1)`.

P.S. In IDE it looks like. But matrix = ValueTuple<int, int> not  ValueTuple<ValueTuple, ValueTuple>

[image]

Comment: Tuple requires at least two values.

Comment: `(x)` isn't a tuple literal - it's just a parenthesized expression. (Changing that would be a massive breaking change.)

Comment: @coder_b We can create a tuple with one value, you can find example in my question.
`ValueTuple.Create(Item1)`

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe there is another way to define a matrix compactly, without `new()'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72599998/402366), C# supports [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

But if you define an extension method like this:

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this List<List<T>> list, params T[] values)
        => list.Add(new List<T>(values));
}
```

you can write code like this:

```cs
var matrix = new List<List<int>>
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 },
};
```

As long as there's an applicable [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), you can use this compact syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your supplementary question in the comments,

> Maybe there is another way to define a matrix compactly, without `new()'?

Have you considered just using a 2D array for the matrix? That's more succinct to initialise. For example, to initialise a matrix of doubles you can do this:

```
var matrix = new [,]
{
    {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
    {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3},
    {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3},
    {3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3},
    {4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3}
};
```